# Reply to receiver as opposed to me

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

When I send a message to someone in Gmail, and then reply to that sent message, it automatically sends the message to the receiver (not me) as opposed to the sender (me). In OWA (Outlook Web Access), when I reply to a message I sent, it sends my reply to me. I find this extremely frustrating. Is there any way to change the Outlook settings so that it functions the same way as Gmail?

Comment: To my knowledge, this behavior/feature is found exclusively in Gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed the same behavior and agree that this feature of Outlook can be annoying.

Try using the Reply-to-All button and that will include all of the original recipients.  You'll want to double check and see if your own address is included as well.  I just tested in Outlook 2010 and everything worked as hoped for.  I sort of recall an older version of Outlook (2007?) including the sender as well.

Comment: +1 for confirmed results (in OWA 14.2.283.3) I confirm that for messages in my 'Sent Items' folder: clicking 'Reply' to a message sent from Mee to Yoo will create a new message addressed to Mee. Clicking 'Reply-all' to the same message creates a new message addressed *only* to Yoo.